# pset3 move function - need some guidance

Tags: function, move

I am trying to figure out how I would need to connect tile number to the array[i][j].

```
 8 | 7 | 6 |
 5 | 4 | 3 |
 2 | 1 |   |
```

So this would be 3x3 board. Empty tile would be board[2][2]. If I would want to move number 1, I should enter 1, and tile int would be 1. while array  number would be board[2][1]. I am trying to figure out how i have connect the 1 to the board[2][1]. And what kind a loop i have to use or it can be done somehow differently?

Comment: are you asking to write the code, or your asking about math/algorithm to work with matrices? Sorry, if I misunderstood you.

Comment: I would like to know math/algorithm... how to start writing it. I want to try writing it myself.